# Setting flag variable in c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have written one code Using property in text box and I am setting some values like this

```
public string Color
{ 
get{}; 
set
  { 
     SetColor(value);
  } 
} 

private void SetColor(string level)
{
    switch(level.ToLower())
    {
     case "high":
     textbox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     break;

     case "medium":
     textbox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
     break;

     case "low":
     textbox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
     break;
   }
}
```

But my main aim is that I need to set flag, if the flag is High it should show red font, similarly if the flag is medium it should show yellow font in label.

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    private static void CheckIsEnum<T>(bool withFlags)
    {
            CheckIsEnum(T) (True);
    }
}

 public static bool IsFlagSet<T>(this T value, T flag)
{
}
```

Will I need to Use a pipe symbol while setting flag variable? I was surfing this on net, but I got answers which I wasn't expecting. One flag Boolean true or false. If the flag is true the color font should be enable according. Also please help me on I need to get data from data base. Will it be possible and see whether the particular value has high, low or medium risk and display font accordingly

Could anyone advice me how to embed the above code in the flags using enum.

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can define an enum with or without Description attribute, but my code will work with both: (you can use description property if your enum value consists of multiple words and you need to show them with spaces like "VeryHigh" as a value but you show it as "Very High" with spaces.)

  ```
  public enum AlertType
  {
      [Description("High")]
      High,

      [Description("Medium")]
      Medium,

      [Description("Low")]
      Low
  }
  ```

Now using some helper methods like what in this helper class, you can get the enum value using a string value which could represent the value/description.

```
    public static class EnumUtils
    {
        public static string StringValueOf(Enum value)
        {
            var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                return attributes[0].Description;
            }
            return value.ToString();
        }


        public static T EnumValueOf<T>(string enumStr)
        {
            string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(T));
            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                var enumVal = (Enum) Enum.Parse(typeof (T), name);
                if (string.Compare(StringValueOf(enumVal), enumStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name);
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("The string is not a description or value of the specified enum.");
        }
    }
```

- Now, regarding your questions :

> > Will I need to Use a pipe symbol while setting flag variable?

No, you don't need that since you cannot combine more than one value from your enum, so for example you cannot say that the Alert is set to High and Low in the same time. [Flags] is useful when your enum values can be combined see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> > Also please help me on I need to get data from data base. will it be possible and see whether the particular value has high ,low or medium risk and display font accordingly.

In this case, you can use the helper methods to convert the enum string to the enum value.

**EDIT**

Looks like you need also a mapping between the AlertType and the Color, so your code can be like this:

```
// your mappings go here.
private Dictionary<AlertType, Color> _alertColorMappings = new Dictionary<AlertType, Color>()
{
    {AlertType.High, Color.Red},
    {AlertType.Medium, Color.Green},
    {AlertType.Low, Color.Yellow},
};

// Alert property which can be set through a mapping with a combobox
private AlertType _alert;
public AlertType Alert
{
    get
    {
        return _alert;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_alert != value)
        {
            _alert = value;
            textbox1.BackColor = _alertColorMappings[value];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alani I need to define various ForeColors like system.drawings.colors; for red ,yellow,green.Will it be possible for me to achieve here

Comment: can you give some details about this, do you need a mapping between the AlertType and the ForeColor ? or something else, if you after the mapping then a dictionary of <AlertType, ForColor> will be enough. ?

Comment: I need to set a flag variable . For instance i have 12345 this is high risk then color red font should be enabled. Please help me in this

Comment: Yes i need a mapping, i have tried with dictionary but i get all the colors at the time in the screen. Can you just provide me a syntax on how to achieve

Comment: Update the question to include what did you try to create the mapping to know where your problem was and help you fix it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include some mapping code.

Comment: Hi could you please specify  what namespace should be used for enumeration

Comment: For Color? It is System.Drawing.

Comment: Ok, What is the namespace for AlertType.  mapping can be done  through combo box or text box. I am trying this in windows form application but getting errors

Comment: It should be your project namespace where you copied the AlertType enum code to.

Comment: So you are saying to add a extension method or dll file

Comment: Why dll?  Just add a new file to your project and paste the enum code there,  unless the enum needs to be accessed fdom different projects then define in a common dll.